My HEAD is different from my checked out branch?
I've checked out a branch but for some reason the HEAD is staying at a different branch.
> git checkout -B myBranch
Reset branch 'myBranch'
> git reset --hard myBranch
HEAD is now at 6f3775fd6 Pull request #123: release/1.2.3.4
# This is the latest commit on the 'dev' branch, NOT on 'myBranch'
> git branch --show-current
myBranch
> cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/myBranch
> git name-rev --name-only HEAD
dev

I've even tried updating the HEAD reference:
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/myBranch

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?
To clarify, this is what I want to happen:
Switch my local repository to the specified branch and update all local files to match the status of the remote branch. Then I want to be able to run the following command to get a list of files changed on the current branch:
git diff --name-only HEAD $(git merge-base HEAD remotes/origin/dev)

This is being performed on a repo stored in a persistent volume claim used in a CI pipeline. When I run the commands on my local computer, they act as expected--I can git switch or git checkout to a branch then run git name-rev --name-only HEAD and it shows the branch name. For some reason this just keeps showing dev and I don't know why.

I think git diff --name-only HEAD $(git merge-base HEAD remotes/origin/dev) can be simplified to git diff --name-only HEAD...remotes/origin/dev (note 3 dots). The docs.

git name-rev only shows a name for the rev you give it. You can see the candidates it's picking from with a core command, git for-each-ref --points-at HEAD, see its docs for what its output means and how you can ask for different info. There's also git log --no-walk --pretty=%D that will give you a different take.
If you only want to see what HEAD's attached to, git symbolic-ref HEAD.

If you were on the dev branch when you said git checkout -B myBranch then everything you are saying is exactly as expected. I assure you that your HEAD is not "different from the checked out branch".
If what is happening isn't what you expected, then your question needs to be clearer about what your intentions were when you gave these commands (and about which command, exactly, is giving you trouble).
Note: If myBranch already existed when you said  git checkout -B myBranch, then you destroyed it and created a new one located at the end of dev. Perhaps that's the part that surprises you.

HEAD is in fact different from the checked out branch--HEAD is dev. Checked out branch is myBranch. When I checkout myBranch, I expect myBranch to be HEAD. How can I make this happen? Can you clarify what you mean by this part: "then you destroyed it and created a new one located at the end of dev"?

@jeremywat you're misunderstanding the purpose of git name-rev, it's a little-used command from Git's earliest days. Everything matt says here is true. You saying "HEAD is dev" is true, but not in the way you think it is. Commits can have any number of names, they're arbitrary, local-use labels you can re-hang at will. You've got HEAD as a symbolic ref for mybranch, but both mybranch and dev are perfectly good names for the commit you've got checked out: they both refer to that commit. If you want to know the name HEAD's using, see my answer.

name-rev is definitely works not the way you expected. git rev-parse HEAD and git rev-parse myBranch should point to the same commit. And i believe they do.

@jthill @Ryan I'm certain that I am misunderstanding how these commands work--I am not good with git so my terminology may be off. I simply want to be able to switch (switch, checkout, whatever) to a certain branch and run the command git diff --name-only HEAD $(git merge-base HEAD remotes/origin/dev) and get a list of files that differ between the dev branch and the branch I'm currently on.

@jthill when I run these commands on my local computer, they act as I'm expecting them to act--I can git switch or git checkout a branch, then run git name-rev --name-only HEAD and it shows the branch I switched to. This is not the case for the repo in question--it just shows dev. Also on my local computer git rev-parse HEAD shows the current commit for whatever branched I switched to, but in the repo in question it always just shows the commit for the dev branch.

@jeremywat well, how about you try what I suggested in my answer? I get it, I've gotten stuck on something plenty of times (once I got someone's name wrong, like, not mispronounced, completely the wrong name) and just couldn't get it right, for days, that was embarrassing enough I still remember it decades later), what I'm trying to tell you is, going on what you've said, you're stuck on a misunderstanding we're trying to get you to look at and actually see.

@jthill looks like git switch instead of git checkout may have fixed my issue to some extent. git symbolic-ref HEAD now shows my desired branch. But I still can't run git merge-base HEAD remotes/origin/dev to find the upstream commit between my branch and dev. Do you know why that would be?
